# Testing a $http Angular service: No pending request to flush

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to write a test for a simple Angular factory that returns a $http.get, but my test fails with "No pending request to flush !".

I've followed a few of the examples I've found online, but nothing works.

Here's my service:

```
angular.module('MPMReportGenerator')
  .factory('sectionService', function ($http, $log) {
    return {
      getSections: function () {
        return $http
          .get('/MPMReportGenerator/api/categories/all')
          .then(function (response) {
            return response.data
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            $log.error('ERROR:', error)
            throw error
          })
        }
      }}
    )
```

And here is my spec:

```
describe('sectionService', function () {
  'use strict'

  var $httpBackend, sectionService, $rootScope
  beforeEach(function () {
    module('MPMReportGenerator')

    inject(function ($injector) {
      $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend')
      $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope')
    })

    inject(function (_sectionService_) {
      sectionService = _sectionService_
    })
  })

  afterEach(function () {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest()
  })

  it('should have sectionService service be defined', function () {
    expect(sectionService).toBeDefined()
  })

  it('should get the section list', function () {
    var sections
    $httpBackend.when('GET', '/MPMReportGenerator/api/categories/all').respond(200)
    sectionService.getSections().then(function (data) {
      sections = data
    })
    $rootScope.$digest()
    expect($httpBackend.flush()).doesNotThrow()
  })
})
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

remove the promise inside factory. your are accessing promise in the controller anyway.just return the http request like this.

```
angular.module('MPMReportGenerator')
    .factory('sectionService', function($http, $log) {
        return {
            getSections: function() {
                return $http
                    .get('/MPMReportGenerator/api/categories/all')
            }
        }
    })
```

access promise in here like this

```
 sectionService.getSections().then(function(response) {
    sections = response.data // the values comes under data property so need to access like this.
 })
```

Comment: Indeed, it makes sense. It doesn't fix the issue with the test, though :/